# How the identity functor looks like?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In Haskell there is an identity function, that just return the feeded value.

```
id :: a -> a
```

There is also the identity functor and how such a functor is defined in Haskell?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: @M.Aroosi of course https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor. But how to interpret it in Haskell?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.3.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html

Comment: From wikipedia: "[The identity functor] maps an object to itself and a morphism to itself." The objects here are types. Can you define a type constructor `data Identity a = ...` that maps any type to itself, and if so, define a `Functor` instance for that type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the identity functor exists:

From the documentation:

> The identity functor and monad.
>
> This trivial type constructor serves two purposes:
>
> - It can be used with functions parameterized by functor or monad classes.
> - It can be used as a base monad to which a series of monad transformers may be applied to construct a composite monad. Most monad transformer modules include the special case of applying the transformer to Identity. For example, State s is an abbreviation for StateT s Identity.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html

The definition in the source is here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Identity.html